# DB2 Scheduled Trigger

Tags: triggers, db2, schedule

I'm new to triggers and I want to ask the proper procedure to create a trigger (or any better methods) to duplicate the contents of T4 table to T5 table on a specified datetime.

For example, on the 1st day of every month at 23:00, I want to duplicate the contents of T4 table to T5 table.
Can anyone please advise what's the best method?

Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG1
   AFTER INSERT ON T4
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO T5 VALUES (:NEW.B, :NEW.A);
   END TRIG1;
```

Comment: Triggers react to operations on a table, not to time. You can use cron or workload schedulers to run tasks.

Comment: What operating-system runs Db2-server? (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) ?  (this will determine the scheduler, and possibly the SQL). If you only need to duplicate the table *occasionally* (for example monthly or weekly, or once per day), consider a different approach. For example, if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can use a scheduled-job that runs  a script to connect to the database, use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ... WITH DATA ... .   Other ways are possible, including populating the target table with LOAD FROM CURSOR etc.

Comment: Thank you. It's running on Redhat Enterprise 6. Can you give me some guidance on how to create the script that can be used by cron?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by Administrative Task Scheduler feature instead of cron.  Here is a sample script.

```
#!/bin/sh

db2set DB2_ATS_ENABLE=YES
db2stop
db2start
db2 -v "drop db db1"
db2 -v "create db db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "CREATE TABLESPACE SYSTOOLSPACE IN IBMCATGROUP MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE EXTENTSIZE 4"
db2 -v "create table s1.t4 (c1 int)"
db2 -v "create table s1.t5 (c1 int)"
db2 -v "insert into s1.t4 values (1)"
db2 -v "create procedure s1.copy_t4_t5() language SQL begin insert into s1.t5 select * from s1.t4; end"
db2 -v "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD ('ATS1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, NULL, '0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *', 'S1', 'COPY_T4_T5',NULL , NULL, NULL )"
date
```

It will create a task, called 'ATS1' and will call the procedure s1.copy_t4_t5 every 10 minuets, such as 01:00, 01:20, 01:30.  You may need to run below after executing the script:
   db2 -v "connect to db1" 
Then, after some time, run below to see if the t5 table has row as expected:
   db2 -v "select * from s1.t5"

For your case, the 5th parameter would be replaced with **'0 23 1 * *'**.
It represents 'minute hour day_of_month month weekday' so
it will be called every 1st day of month at 23:00.

For more information, how to modify existing task, delete task, review status, see at:
**Administrative Task Scheduler routines and views**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061223.html

Also, here is one of good article about it:
**[DB2 LUW] Sample administrative task scheduler ADMIN_TASK_ADD and ADMIN_TASK_REMOVE usage**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1140388?lang=en

Hope this helps.